# AWS-amplify Including the cognito Authorization header in the request

Tags: react-native, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I have create an AWS mobile hub project including the Cognito and Cloud logic. In my API gateway, I set the Cognito user pool for the Authorizers. I use React native as my client side app. How can I add the Authorization header to my API request.

```
const request = {
  body: {
    attr: value
  }
};

API.post(apiName, path, request)
  .then(response => {
  // Add your code here
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
  });
};
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

By default, the API module of `aws-amplify` will attempt to sig4 sign requests.  This is great if your Authorizer type is `AWS_IAM`.

This is obviously *not* what you want when using a Cognito User Pool Authorizer.  In this case, you need to pass the id_token in the `Authorization` header, instead of a sig4 signature.

Today, you can indeed pass an `Authorization` header to amplify, and [it will no longer overwrite it with the sig4 signature](https://github.com/aws/aws-amplify/issues/37).

---

In your case, you just need to add the `headers` object to your `request` object.  For example:

```js
async function callApi() {

    // You may have saved off the JWT somewhere when the user logged in.
    // If not, get the token from aws-amplify:
    const user = await Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser();
    const token = user.signInUserSession.idToken.jwtToken;

    const request = {
        body: {
            attr: "value"
        },
        headers: {
            Authorization: token
        }
    };

    var response = await API.post(apiName, path, request)
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        });

    document.getElementById('output-container').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(response);
}
```

Tested using `aws-amplify` 0.4.1.

Comment: I'm getting error 304 IncompleteSignatureException

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer only works if your endpoint doesn't have aws_iam authorization, otherwise you'll hit IncompleteSignatureException. The solution is attach the id_token to a custom header (eg: jwt-token) and remember to whitelist that custom header in your apigateway.